# get information from pandas' dataframe and python 3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two csv files. Contacts and Users.

**How I load data into dataframes and merge them**

First, I load a dataframe with the name of the users:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df_users= pd.read_csv('./Users_001.csv',sep=',',usecols=[0,2,3])
```

Then I load the information from contacts of each user

```
df_contacts = pd.read_csv('./Contacts_001.csv',sep=',',usecols=[0,1,5,48,55,56,57,83,58])
```

df_users columns name are: `user_id, Name, Surname`

df_contacts columns name are:  `Contact ID, id user owner, fullname, qualification, ...`

I want to merge both dataframes using `user_id` and `'id user owner'` since they represent the same information. To to this I first change the name of the columns on `df_contacts` and then I merge

```
dfcontactos.columns = ['ID de Contacto','user_id','fullname','qualification','accesibility' ... ]
df_us_cont = pd.merge(dfcontactos,df_usuarios,on='user_id')
```

Now `df_us_cont` has the information from users and contacts.

**What I want to do**

There are only 18 `user_id` but there are 500 contacts. For each user I want to know:

- Number of contacts with qualification < 100

  For the contacts that have qualification <100

  How many contacts have accesibility >= 4

  Accesibility is a discrete number (0-5))
- Number of contacts with qualification > 100 and < 300
- Number of contacts with qualification > 300
  -

**What I have tried and fail**

```
df_qua_lower100 = df_us_cont[df_us_cont['qualification']<100]
df_qua_lower100['user_id'].value_counts()
```

So far with this I am able to get the information on how many contacts with `qualification<100` has each `user_id`. But I am unable to look how many have '`accesibility>=4`'

I have tried to explain the best I could

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you can merge without changing column names

```
df_us_cont = dfcontactos.merge(dfcontactos,left_on='id user owner',right_on='user_id')
```

You can add as many conditions as you want if you use loc

```
df_us_cont.loc[(df_us_cont['qualification']<100) & (df_us_cont['accesibility']>=4),'user_id'].value_counts()
```

Number of contacts with qualification > 100 and < 300

```
df_us_cont.loc[(df_us_cont['qualification']>100) &(df_us_cont['qualification']<300) & (df_us_cont['accesibility']>=4),'user_id'].value_counts()
```

Number of contacts with qualification > 300

```
df_us_cont.loc[(df_us_cont['qualification']>300) & (df_us_cont['accesibility']>=4),'user_id'].value_counts()
```